# Carregar apenas div de um site especifica

Tags: java, html, android

Ola eu estou a tentar tirar toda a informação de uma pagina para uma webview via jsoup mas as letras ficam todas deformadas quando carrego e não fica como esta no site , ha alguma maneira de carregar o site , mas apenas a div que eu quero, que neste caso é a div "inside2" ?

Este é o site : http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/detcursopi.asp?codc=8184&code=0400

Código em que faz load da informação mas fica deformado :

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Bundle CursoInfoData = getIntent().getExtras();

        site = CursoInfoData.getString("site");

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(site).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         ele = doc.select(".inside2");
        return "start";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #01A9DB; background-color: #FFFFFF;}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + ele.toString()
                + "</body></html>";
        cursoInfoWeb.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

[image: Fica deformado como mostro nesta imagem]

Comment: a página usa iso-8859-1 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">